# How to create a relative URL for Visual Force Pages

Tags: url, salesforce, visualforce

We are using Visual Force Pages built on Salesforce for our HR tool. The issue I am running into is we are unable to link to any pages in our employee portal because each person's ID is included in the URL. If I were to provide a link, it would instead bring that user to my profile.

How can I use wildcards in the URL to bring each user to the link with their own ID in the URL (it would be near impossible to ask users to enter it themselves)?

Task:
In our HR portal we have an internal career portal and marketing would like to link to it in an email. However, any attempt to make a link will just link to the profile of the person that grabbed the link (except for that person, it has the desired outcome). This is because part of the URL includes a person's ID. I need to pass that ID through some how.

URL Example:
https://theHRwebsite.vf.force.com/apex/CollaborationPortalIndex?id=UNIQUEEMPLOYEEID#/teammember/UNIQUEEMPLOYEEID/services/a2k58000000v63mAAA/processes/a2r58000000rd4JAAQ

The section I believe needs to be replaced is the **UNIQUEEMPLOYEEID**. I am unsure if it matters, but this section is normally 18 characters with mixed numbers and letters. The /services/a2k58000000v63mAAA/processes/a2r58000000rd4JAAQ is the path I believe users actually need to follow.

Correction: I now see that two of the spots are identical and have updated the URL to reflect that. One of which has an extra # at the end. I retried all the things at the bottom now in both places and still have the same results.

Things I tried replacing it with (assume I am very capable of error)
*
'*
*?
?
'*?
'
??????????????????

---

I was hoping these would act as wildcards and populate the relative user's ID.